# windows command-line script(script.bat) for starting elasticsearch nodes

Tags: powershell, batch-file, command-prompt

I have two elasticsearch services installed through:

```
service install node1
service install node2
```

I am trying to start elasticsearch nodes running a script.bat file with these two commands:

```
service start node1
service start node2
```

The output on the command line is:

```
C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Work\ElasticSearch\elasticsearch-1.3.1\bin>script.bat

C:\Users\User1Desktop\Work\ElasticSearch\elasticsearch-1.3.1\bin>service start node1
The service 'node1' has been started

C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Work\ElasticSearch\elasticsearch-1.3.1\bin>
```

The script is starting node1. But it is not starting node2. It is probably because the first command is taking time and .bat script is not intelligent enough to handle this delay. Is this a limitation of command line .bat scripts? Should I use a different scripting tool like powershell scripts, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the `service` program itself a .bat file: `service.bat`? If so, then you must execute it from another .bat file via `call` command:

```
call service start node1
call service start node2
```

Comment: Yes service is itself a .bat file. Thanks! It worked.